# Перебор цикла для вывода списка (постов например) Вордпресс

Tags: php, wordpress

Работаю с Вордпрессом и столкнулся с проблемой.
Не получается реализовать следующее:

```
<ul class="list-menu">
   <?php 
     foreach($terms as $key=>$term) { ?>
        <li><a href="<?=get_term_link($term->slug,$t_name)?>"><?= $term->name?></a></li>
   <?php if($key == 5) {
            break;
           }
      }?>
     <li onclick="javascript:collaps_left_menu('<?= $k?>')" id="collapse-btn-<?= $k?>" class="show-all">Show all</li>
</ul>
```

Нужно выводить только первых 5 постов, далее при клике на "Show all" показывать остальной весь список.

Сам вывод 5 постов сделал, а как быть с подгрузкой остальных при клике?

Answer (score 2):

Так ничего не выйдет. Для начала надо понимать, что код php выполняется на сервере, а js - в браузере. Технология, которая позволяет им взаимодействовать, называется ajax. Схематично ajax работает таким образом:

1. При обращении к сайту отрабатывает php-код, который формирует html страницы, со стилями и js-скриптами. Страницу php отдаёт веб-серверу (apache или nginx), а тот - браузеру. php заканчивает работу и забывает об этой странице навсегда.
2. Браузер, получив страницу, отображает ее на экране пользовательского устройства.
3. Пользователь нажимает на кнопку "загрузить еще". Срабатывает событие, по событию запускается скрипт, он отправляет ajax-запрос на сервер.
4. Сервер получает запрос, отдает в php. Происходит новая инициализация WordPress, запускается пользовательский код, специально написанный под ajax. Код php вынимает дополнительные посты из базы, формирует html-код с их отображением, возвращает веб-серверу, а тот - браузеру клиента.
5. Браузер, получив кусок html, с помощью скрипта вставляет его в отображаемую на экране страницу.

Как всё это выстроить в WordPress, подробно расписано [тут](https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html).

А для начала можно применить любой из плагинов, которые можно найти в репозитории WordPress по строке "Load More".