# Проблема с аяксом

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Сайт написан по схеме MVC. В общем в чем собственно проблема. Когда отправляю данные с помощью AJAX:

```
$('#entrance').click(function() {
  $.ajax ({
    url: "/components/log-in.php",
    type:"POST",
    data:({name: $("#name").val(),passwd: $("#passwd").val()}),
    dataType: "html",
    success: function funcScs(data){
      $('.header-info').text(data);
    }
  });
});
```

Возникает проблема в файле исполнения:

```
<?php  
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $passwd = $_POST['passwd'];
  function getUser($name,$passwd){
    $data = array();
    $db = Db::getConnection();
    $result = $db->query("SELECT*FROM `users` WHERE `user_name` = $name AND `user_password`=$passwd ");
  }
  echo getUser($name,$passwd);
?>
```

Когда данные приходят, то скрипт выдает ошибку:

> **Fatal error**: Uncaught Error: Class 'Db' not found in
>   W:\domains\hozplus.com\components\log-in.php:6 Stack trace: #0
>   W:\domains\hozplus.com\components\log-in.php(10): getUser('admin',
>   'admin') #1 {main} thrown in
>   **W:\domains\hozplus.com\components\log-in.php** on line
>   **6**

Но, класс `Db` я изначально подключаю в файле index.php :

```
<?php 
  ini_set('display_errors',1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);

  define('ROOT', dirname(__FILE__));
  require_once(ROOT.'/components/Router.php');
  require_once(ROOT.'/components/Db.php');

  $router = new Router();
  $router->run();
?>
```

Тем более и в контроллерах, и в моделях (которые лежат в отдельных папках), он такой ошибки не выдает, хотя я обращаюсь к этому классу точно так-же.
Вот собственно вопрос: 
ПОЧЕМУ он не может найти класс `Db`, если до этого я уже подключал index?

Comment: Вы вызываете log-in.php. Он подключает index? ))

Comment: Нет, нет.проблема, что он выдает ошибку, что Db класс не найден , хотя  в контроллерах и моделях он его видит, потому что в index я его уже подключал

Comment: Почитайте вот это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/688786/220220  там про WordPress, но это неважно. Смысл взаимодействия php-js везде одинаковый

Comment: @NONAME у вас же спросили log-in.php подключает index.php? В том коде что вы предоставили где возникает ошибка я не вижу что вы там подключили Db, а если и есть то где инициализация?

Comment: файл-исполнения это отдельный фейспалм, но если у вас нету подключение *файла-исполнителя* в индексе и наоборот , то очевидно подключение нужно установить в файле на который ссылается ajax

Comment: Все, понял в чем ошибка и исправил,забыл, что все запросы проходят через роутер и формируется определенная ссылка, всем спасибо за советы\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Основная проблема этого скрипта, это идиот сидящий за компом(я), сайт работает по MVC, из маршрутов берется uri,и на его основе формируется controller и action ,следовательно, для обработки аякса нужен не просто файл с названием и путем к папке,а именно контроллер и action в котором аякс будет все обрабатывать, прошу прощения, что всех потревожил